# How to check if topologies are the same?

Tags: general-topology

Let $(X,\mathcal{T})$ be topological space. Let $A$ be a set such that $A \subseteq X$. Show that family $\mathcal{T}_A := \{U \cup (V \cap A) \mid U, V \in \mathcal{T} \}$ is a topology on X. I have show shown that it is a topology, now I have to check if topologies are the same.

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Please use the [mathjax basic tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference), review the [meta read](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question) and enhance your question. It helps to include context (i.e., your attempts, motivation, etc).

Comment: If $A \subset T$, $A$ is a set of open sets in $(X, T)$, so $V \cap A$ doesn't make sense for $U \in T$. Did you mean $A \in T$?

Answer (score 0):

$A = \emptyset \cup (X \cap A) \in \mathcal{T}_A$. So the topologies are the same iff $A \in \mathcal{T}$ i.e. iff $A$ is open. Otherwise $A \in \mathcal{T}_A\setminus \mathcal{T}$ and the topology is strictly finer (taking $V=\emptyset$ in the definition shows that $\mathcal{T}\subseteq \mathcal{T}_A$ always).

Comment: So in this example A is not open? Am I right?

Comment: @mode100 we have to assume that $A$ is not open to get a new topology.